# css and image conflicts on. htaccess rewriterule

Tags: php, .htaccess

I saw many similar problems to what I am experiencing but I already followed every solutions I get from it and it seems that I can't make it run without conflicts.

HTML CSS calls:

```
<head>
<base href="http://localhost/smartwavedev.sw_apiwebtool/" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/login.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/dashboard.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/docs.css" type="text/css">
</head>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?page=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?page=$2&nav=$3
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. "It can't run without conflicts" isn't one - what conflicts, what goes wrong, what do you suspect the problem is?

Comment: the css and image files cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this condition is malformed:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
```

It should just be:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Now it will trigger on all files. Next up, a `RewriteCond` will only match for the **first** `RewriteRule` following it. So the third rule with the 3 elements is still matching (and thus blocking) your CSS files. You either need to repeat the `RewriteCond` lines for all rules, or implement a better solution. For your specific case, I'd really recommend dropping the entire concept of rewriting and replace it with:

```
 FallbackResource index.php
```

And then parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in the `index.php` file.

Comment: Thank you. I solved it by repeating the rewritecond before all the rules.